# Pragma mark in Objective C comments in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, preprocessor

The normal `#pragma mark - Some group` pattern can be used in Xcode to add a divider + grouping name to the method list in Xcode. You can also do things like `// TODO: Finish him` to have todos similarly show up.

Now, I seem to recall there used to be a way to do the pragma-style divider+topic by using comments, something to the tune of `// mark - Some group` but it doesn’t seem to work for me in Xcode 5.

The closest I can come is with `// MARK: whatever`, but that shows up in the list literally as `MARK: whatever`, instead of the similar list item you’d get from the `#pragma mark` statement.

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Why don't you just use `#pragma mark - ...`? If it does everything you need why don't you just use it?

Comment: @Fogmeister Because that’s not what I’m asking :)

Comment: It's a bit confusing then. "Normal pragma mark used to add divider groups"... "Have TODO show up also"... "how to have divider topics?" Is a divider+topic different from a divider+grouping? Sounds the same to me. Not really sure what you are asking for then. Could you clear up exactly what you are looking for that isn't achieved with `#pragma mark -`